# How to activate breakpoints in a BPL file?

Tags: delphi, breakpoints, bpl

I'm using Delphi 10.4.

I have a Delphi executable `XXX.exe` and a Delphi package `BBB.Bpl`, which is loaded by `XXX` with `LoadPackage('BBB.Bpl')`.

Both are separate projects in Delphi.

I open the `BBB.Bpl` project, indicating my `XXX.exe` as the Host application. After a build of `BBB`, blue dots on the right side of the editor are visible, and breakpoints can be set in the `BBB` code.

When I start the `BBB` project with eg. <kbd>F9</kbd>, the `XXX` application performs the `LoadPackage` procedure without fail, and executes the commands from the `BBB` without fail. But, the breakpoints in the `BBB` code are disabled, also the blue dots are not visible. The breakpoints in the code of the `XXX` application are working fine.

I Googled a lot about this, nothing was helpful.

I tried to check and add more search paths, lots of compiler/linker options (Debug information = true, etc), but I am not able to debug the Bpl's source code.

Can anyone please give me some hints?

Comment: Are you sure that you are loading the exact copy of the .BPL you have in your IDE? Are you using a fully qualified path to load the .BPL? If not, it's possible that the actual .BPL file you are loading is another one than what you think...

Comment: I have only one BPL on my computer. If I change the BPL code, this changes are compiled an executed.

Answer (score 1):

you should attach it(bpl) to main app when the app was running as below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I used the Run | Load Process... | Local -> Load dialog to run my host applicatin and it worked.

Comment: This should not be necessary. By setting XXX as the Host for BBB, and then running BBB, the IDE will run XXX and detect its loading of BBB at runtime, and *should* enable debugging of BBB automatically. Typically, this breaks if the IDE can't find BBB's debug info (ie, via TDS file) and/or source code.